# Is it possible to list Azure Blobs in a container having public link only?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm developing C# application component that will download files from my client's public containers. It seems that the default method of accessing Azure Blob Containers as in docs:

```
string storageConnectionString = "...";

CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
CloudBlobClient serviceClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();

var container = serviceClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
```

My client sent me a link to theirs public blob container, such as `https://clientstoragename.blob.core.windows.net/containername/`.

Is it possible to enumerate all blobs in this container using Azure original nuget package if this link is all that I have?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to enumerate all blobs in this container using Azure
>   original nuget package if this link is all that I have?

Yes, it is entirely possible to do so. Just append `restype=container&comp=list` to the end of the URL and put that in a browser's address bar and you should see a list of all blobs (up to 5000) in XML format. Your URL would be `https://clientstoragename.blob.core.windows.net/containername?restype=container&comp=list`.

If you're writing code to do so, you'll just do a `GET` request on that URL and parse the response XML.

Please see this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. The question wasn't about REST endpoint, it was about whether the proper nuget library exists for this purpose.

Comment: You don't really need Azure Storage Nuget package. In fact, I don't think you can use that. You can use WebClient or any other class that is capable of making HTTP request and get the data.